# Compress static javascript files in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, compression, uglifyjs

In my app I use from facebookincubator `create-react-app` repositorium. After some works I deploy my app on server and testing by PageSpeed Insights from Google.

My feedback from test is that I don't have compressed statc javascript file, which weight could be reduced from 1MB to 150kB. Is possible to uglify javascript file?
In this repositorium I can't find webpack config, could you tell me when I switch compressing ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that **[minifying](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources) and [compressing](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/EnableCompression) resources are two different things**.

---

You are referring to minifying your JavaScript resources. `create-react-app`'s build script ships with the option to **create a production build**, which among other things also **minifies the JavaScript**.

For a production environment, you should build your app this way:

```
npm run build
```

---

Compression generally refers to **gzip compression** of the files delivered to the client and needs to be configured in your web server. For more info, see the Google insights page regarding compression I linked above.

Comment: Yes I build to production by npm run build. I have turn on gzip